# riak-cs create bucket fails with : bucket does not exist

Tags: riak-cs

I'm attempting to create a bucket in RiakCS using a curl PUT command. And the command is failing. This is the command I'm giving:

```
curl -ks https://p-riakcs.example.com/user:secret/riak/test -XPUT -H Content-Type:application/json --data-binary '{"props":{"n_val":5}}'
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>NoSuchBucket</Code><Message>The specified bucket does not exist.</Message><Resource>/user:secret/riak/test</Resource><RequestId></RequestId></Error>
```

I was under the impression if I give RiakCS the name of a new bucket, it should create the new bucket on the fly.

How can I give this command correctly and create a new bucket in riakcs?

Comment: Which do you use exactly, riak kv or riak cs? If you are using riak cs, you should access in S3 API way, e.g. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUT.html .

Comment: I'm using riak-cs.Thanks for the link. I'll check it out!